# How to keep two instances of Active Directory synchonized

Tags: active-directory

I am having a nightmare with my Integration Team. We have two platforms, Dev and Integration. Each have an instance of Active Directory (AD) but they are not synchronized. Every time I develop something, it works fine in the Dev platform, but the moment the Integration team deploys my app in the Integration platform, there are error messages popping up.

I am wasting a lot of time debugging the application, only to find out that some AD attributes were renamed in the INT platform. Only to find out that the AD in the INT platform was tampered, and not the same as the Dev platform.

How can a developer ensure that the two instances are identical?

Comment: I assume you're asking about how to compare the schema in both instances? Ideally, changes should be made in the dev environment and tested there *before* implementing in production. That's the root of the problem here.

Comment: [You sure could](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd547839(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)